# Single Page Application framework and login page?

Tags: jquery, html, coldfusion, single-page-application, coldfusion-2016

I have worked on a project Single Page Application, created inside of an existing system. Our old, existing system has a framework created in our company. This framework is very old and is not mobile friendly.

Now I have a project to move my SPA to separate framework. This will require creating new Login page as well as masking decision on what framework I should use for this single page app. Code that I develop used JQuery, HTML5, CSS and ColdFusion 2016 on the back end.

I do not have experience with creating Login systems and I'm not sure how to decide what to use and where to start. 
Not only that, I'm debating what framework I should use? Would JQuery be enough or I should move to Angular or something else?

If anyone can help me where to look and start please let me know. Any blogs or articles would be greatly appreciated. I have searched around but I haven't found much. There is a lot of debates on SPA frameworks. This application is a state wide product. I need different access levels in my system. In other words it's not just simple SPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're replacing your existing Single Page Application with a new one.  From what I'm reading you're requirements are

1. It needs to be mobile friendly.
2. It needs to be a Single Page Application.
3. Backend using ColdFusion 2016.
4. Requires user logins and session management.

Me personally, I'm experienced with ColdFusion, jQuery, HTML5, Bootstrap.  I have no experience with AngularJS.  As you know, ColdFusion is perfect for dealing with login/session managemnt.  So given your requirements and what I know, I would suggest using

- ColdFusion (seems like a given, also provides login/session mgmt).
- Bootstrap 4 (mobile friendly, mobile first).
- AngularJS (for the SPA requirement).
- jQuery (needed for Bootstrap).

Hope this helps with your decision making on what direction to begin your development.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you I would Start designing in Bootstrap with Jquery which is so easy for the single page application. When using ColdFusion you will have Hash for the security encryption..